# Draw rectangle in canvas using fabricjs Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, fabricjs

i'm trying to draw rectangle inside canvas on mouseclick event, but i'm still getting some issues! canvas.on('selection:created') event on canvas but it's not firing.

here's my code

```
let can = new fabric.Canvas('fabricCanvas_' + page._pageIndex);
this.initCanvas_rect(can);

initCanvas_rect(canvas: any) {
    var line, isDown= false, startPosition: { x: number; y: number; }, rect: fabric.Rect,drawingMode=true;
    canvas.on('mouse:down', (options : any) => {
      if (!drawingMode){
      isDown = true;
      startPosition = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
          rect=new fabric.Rect({
              left:startPosition.x,
              top:startPosition.y,
              width:0,
              height:0,
              stroke:'red',
              strokeWidth:3,
              fill:''
          });
          canvas.add(rect);
        }
    });
    canvas.on('mouse:up', (options:any) => {
      isDown = false;
      canvas.add(rect);
    });
    canvas.on('mouse:move', (options:any) => {
      if (!isDown || !drawingMode) {
      let endPosition = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
      canvas.setWidth(Math.abs( endPosition.x-startPosition.x ));
      canvas.setHeight(Math.abs( endPosition.y -startPosition.y ));
      canvas.renderAll();
      }
    });
    canvas.on('selection:created', (options:any) => {
      drawingMode = false;   
    });
    canvas.on('selection:cleared', (options:any) => {
      drawingMode = true;   
    });
  }
```

any help please! Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved when these modifications were applied.

```
initCanvas_rect(canvas: any) {
    var line, isDown= false, startPosition: { x: number; y: number; }, rect: fabric.Rect,drawingMode=true;
    canvas.on('mouse:down', (options : any) => {
      console.log("mouse:down", drawingMode)
      if (drawingMode){
      isDown = true;
      console.log(options.e.clientX,options.e.clientY);
      startPosition = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
          rect=new fabric.Rect({
              left:startPosition.x,
              top:startPosition.y,
              width:0,
              height:0,
              stroke:'red',
              strokeWidth:3,
              fill:''
          });
          rect.lockRotation = true;
          canvas.add(rect);
        }
    });

    canvas.on('mouse:up', (options:any) => {
      console.log("mouse:up")
      isDown = false;
      canvas.add(rect);
    });

    canvas.on('mouse:move', (options:any) => {
      console.log("mouse:move",'isDown ',isDown,"drawingMode ",drawingMode )
      if (isDown || drawingMode) {
      let endPosition = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
      rect.set('width', Math.abs( endPosition.x-startPosition.x ));
      rect.set('height', Math.abs( endPosition.y-startPosition.y ));

      canvas.renderAll();
      }
    });

    canvas.on('selection:created', (options:any) => {
      console.log('selection:selected')
      drawingMode = false;   
    });

    canvas.on('selection:cleared', (options:any) => {
      console.log('selection:cleared')
      drawingMode = true;   
    });
  }
```